# different ways of code writing. need suggestion

Tags: php

My friend writes everything using phps echo.

I mean he starts `<?` and echo everything, including header, main part, footer, he even has style.php file where he echos some css and then includes it in main project.

question is why is it better to do that way ? Or is it better at all?

Cause in dreamveawer everything is red. I mean it understands evrything as phps srtings and makes all text red.

If you do not use echo you have different colors in code and you can see where is ccs, javascript or html.

So what's better to write normally or I should try the same "echo everything" practice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is no better to do that way.

Do not use echo to output HTML but divide your code into 2 parts - business logic part and presentation logic part, a latter one consists of mostly HTML with PHP used only to output data coming from the business logic part

a little example of such a template:

```
<? if ($err): ?>
  <? foreach($err as $e): ?>
<div class="err"><?=$e?></div>
  <? endforeach ?>
<? endif ?>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$form['name']?>">
  <textarea name="comments"><?=$form['comments']?></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok I was writing the same way from the start. But can you explain what does his method is trying to do ? Why do he puts everything inside "echo" ?

Comment: isn't it better to ask him? I can't say for him, I can only guess. It can be old habit based on some bad tutorial maybe. in fact, 99% of online PHP tutorials are nightmare. including SO answers as well. ok, so goes for 90%

Answer (score 4):

If that's how he does it, then please slap him across the back of the head for us please?

But seriously, there is this thing called [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), please take a look at it, comprehend it, implement it and explain it to your friend.

Comment: You could wrap views inside of `echo` as well though.. :(

Comment: You're correct, and I do, but not for entire pages. Only tidbits.

Answer (score 1):

That's horrendous.

You should try not to mix PHP and HTML if you can help it.

In some cases you *will* be interleaving some dynamic content with static content (and you could use a templating engine for that); but outputting the *entire* HTML document via PHP statements is a clear sign of insanity and sadism.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML code instead of echoing has the advantage that the editor (Dreamweaver in your case) can do syntax highlighting. This will help you find errors in your HTML faster.

Also, you don't have to think too much about escaping quotes in your HTML (you still need to think about proper escaping your PHP variables anyway).

I can think of several ways the bad habit of echoing everything can be formed:

- Errors from missing PHP tags while intermingling PHP and HTML. For a newbie it takes a while to wrap your head around the concept of using one language (PHP) to write code in another language (HTML). I remember when I first learned PHP I thought it would be easier to echo everything instead of opening and closing PHP tags all the time.
- Coming from a language background where every output must be printed explicitly.
- Having read some insane micro-optimization article on the web that claims echoing is faster or more secure.

Comment: I understand that, but what I want to understand is what does echo method gives?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in templates. They're not html nor php, but a combination between these two.
The advantage is that you can see/edit/update/maintain your code much easier, because the actual php part is somewhat separated from the html markup.
The main disadvantage is that it might be a bit slower, since php reads the template, makes replacements and then spits out the html.

[Here's a link](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/) to some of the most used php template engines.